# Who makes sample packs and why?

Tags: samples

Dubstep music is usually heavily loaded with samples. It's my goal to make my own high quality samples to be unique. However at times I struggle to make anything sound decent, so I resort to buying samples from Beaport. When I listen to the samples I'm overwhelmed by the sound quality and how accurate they are to the sound I'm looking for.

This makes me wonder... Who makes these samples? If they're that good why aren't they producing their own full length tracks. If they are producing themselves surely they'd keep their samples to themselves as opposed to helping the competition?

This might appear to be a daft question but if I had the skill to to sound design to that extent. I'd use it to its full potential!

A google search didn't help me with this question.

Comment: Simple answer: turn the tables and look at sound effects libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These packs are mostly made by producers who are working under their own moniker too. The reason to produce them is simple, if you are an experienced producer, it's pretty much the easiest and less time consuming thing to make loops and samples then sell them on these sites. People don't have to buy music to listen, they can stream for free. But if you want to produce, then you need the WAV files on your computer. So sometimes it can be better income for a producer than selling music, as for beginners it's easier to buy these samples and loops, than spending years with production work to learn how to make their own.